# Verify a path in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I have to write a program in Python that receive a root path from command line. I parsed the given arguments with **argparse** module. Now, I have to check if the given path contains 2 folders. If not, I have to make a join between the actual path and those folders.

---

For example, I have the `given_path="C:\Users\user\Downloads"` and I want to verify if the given_path contains the folders "\documents\doc", after "..\Downloads" .

Also, the given_path differs from one input to another, but the 2 folders are always the same.

---

```
def main():
ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","--input_file", required=True, help="Root project path")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())
auxPath=args['input_file'].replace("\\","/")

if not os.path.exists(auxPath):
    path=os.path.join(auxPath, 'documents/doc')
else:
    path=auxPath

add_line(path) #add a text line into the specifix file
```

I tried to use os.path.exists(), but it does not do the right thing.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: How do you use it, share your code please, and explain *does not do the right thing*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to check for the folder existence is:

```
os.path.isdir( os.path.join( root, folder))
```

because `os.path.exists()` will return `True` for the simple file as well.